# threads that not working to copy a file into queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to do a function that reads information from a file into a queue and then another function that reads the information from the queue to a file. Both functions are enabled by threads. The problem is that the first function does not store the information correctly and I do not know why? can anyone help me?
This is the code:

```
void MessagesSender::saveMessages()
{
 std::string line = "";
 std::ifstream file(FILE_TO_READ);

if (file.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        mutReadToFile.lock();
        this->message.push(line);
        mutReadToFile.unlock();
    }
    file.close();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Faild" << std::endl;
}
std::ofstream removeFile(FILE_TO_READ, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc); //to delete the file
std::cout << "wait a minute..." << std::endl;
//std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
```

}

and the other function:

```
void MessagesSender::sendMessages()
{
std::ofstream file;
std::vector<std::string> connectUsers;

connectUsers = this->getConnectUsers();
file.open(FILE_TO_WRITE, std::ios::app);

if (file.is_open())
{
    while (!this->message.empty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < connectUsers.size(); i++)
        {
            file << connectUsers[i] << ": " << this->message.front() << std::endl;
        }
        mutReadToFile.lock();
        this->message.pop();
        mutReadToFile.unlock();
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << "Copy successfully" << std::endl;
}
else //If the file doesn't open
{
    std::cout << "faild :(" << std::endl;;
}
```

}

this is the menu:

```
int main()
{
MessagesSender mess;
mess.printMenu();

std::thread read(&MessagesSender::saveMessages, mess);
std::thread write(&MessagesSender::sendMessages, mess);

read.join();
write.join();
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Unrelated: Try to replace the direct lock-unlock calls on a mutex with a RAII wrapper like [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock). When you manually unlock sooner or later you find a case, often an exception, where the unlock is skipped.

Comment: Threads aren't copyable. You rather want to have a fixed number of threads, which fetch work items from your queue.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But do you have any idea yet how to fix my problem?

Comment: Please expand on *does not store the information correctly*. What does it do? Normally I'd take your code, run it, and see for myself, but because this question doesn't contain a [mre] or a complete code sample that I can run, I'm unable to do this. Thorny problems with thread synchronization almost always need some sort of runnable example to fully understand and explain.

Comment: `while (!this->message.empty())` is not properly synchronized. The bad could be here, but the bad could be dancing gremlins on line 4897. A MRE helps eliminate problems with the unseen and allows you to focus on one and only one problem.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to help with synchronization?

Comment: Have you considered using multiple buffers and synchronization variables?  Each buffer would have a synchronization variable set to "writing in process", "reading in process" and "available". The read-from-file thread would check a buffer for "available", if available, it changes the status to "reading in process".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads use copies of the MessagesSender.

```
std::thread read(&MessagesSender::saveMessages, mess);
std::thread write(&MessagesSender::sendMessages, mess);
```

These bind by value. Use `std::ref` to prevent copying `mess`:

```
std::thread read(&MessagesSender::saveMessages, std::ref(mess));
std::thread write(&MessagesSender::sendMessages, std::ref(mess));
```

Alternatively, use pointers:

```
std::thread read(&MessagesSender::saveMessages, &mess);
std::thread write(&MessagesSender::sendMessages, &mess);
```

### Live Demo

As always, let me add a live demo.

It also

- shows how to use lock_guard or unique_lock to use exception safe locking
- fixes the operations (empty() was a data race because it was outside the lock)
- uses C++11 ranged for
- makes error handling on the filestreams idiomatic
- FIXES the misleading comment on the truncation (no file is removed, otherwise, just `std::remove` it?)
- uses RAII for ifstream/ofstream instead of manual close()

There are "bigger" functional issues:

- I've ASSUMED that you want the messages to be repeated for all connected users, instead of popping each time.
- There's a race condition. If your sendMessages thread starts too soon, it will just exit because the queue is empty. This is by design in your code. I'll leave that as an exorcism for the reader.

I might be forgetting some

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12141bcc24ac28e7)**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

static const std::string FILE_TO_READ = "input.txt";
static const std::string FILE_TO_WRITE = "output.txt";

struct MessagesSender {
    std::mutex _queueMutex;

    std::vector<std::string> getConnectUsers() {
        return { "john", "alice", "bob" };
    }
    void printMenu() { std::cout << "I don't know what's for dinner\n"; }
    void sendMessages();
    void saveMessages();

    std::queue<std::string> _messages;
};

void MessagesSender::saveMessages()
{
    std::string line;
    {
        std::ifstream file(FILE_TO_READ);

        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            std::lock_guard lock(_queueMutex);
            _messages.push(line);
        }
        if (!file.good() && !file.eof()) {
            std::cout << "Faild" << std::endl;
        }
    } // closes file
    {
        std::ofstream removeFile(FILE_TO_READ, std::ios::trunc); // to empty the file
    }
    std::cout << "Input closed" << std::endl;
}

// and the other function:

void MessagesSender::sendMessages()
{
    std::ofstream file(FILE_TO_WRITE, std::ios::app);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "faild :(" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    auto const connectUsers = MessagesSender::getConnectUsers();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
    while (!_messages.empty())
    {
        auto current = _messages.front();
        _messages.pop();

        lock.unlock();

        for (const auto& user : connectUsers) {
            file << user << ": " << current << std::endl;
        }

        lock.lock();
    }
    std::cout << "Copy successfully" << std::endl;
}

// this is the menu:

int main()
{
    MessagesSender mess;
    mess.printMenu();

    std::thread read(&MessagesSender::saveMessages, &mess);
    std::thread write(&MessagesSender::sendMessages, &mess);

    read.join();
    write.join();
}
```

Comment: Added full review + live demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12141bcc24ac28e7 Pay attention especially the functional problems with the code.